# Is it possible to run multiple Air clients in the same project (Intellij IDEA)

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, air, adobe

Basically, I need to test some multiplayer functionality, and it would be more than useful to have two Air instances running at the same time.

The only way I could achieve this was creating two different projects, however it's quite cumbersome.

Is there any way to do it inside the same project?.

It is possible to do it if you use the Flash player instead though.

Comment: why would it be cumbersome? If your project and main class is full of code I would understand but that would be just a bad setup to start with anyway. Quite easy if everything is in a library and your project is only a main class with a few lines of code or at the least everything comes from a source path.

Comment: If you want all of this on desktop, then maybe to create several instances of the NativeWindow would help. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restriction only connected with the fact that your air-app id (which defined in app descriptor) always should be unique.

So, you could set up few flash build configurations in your module in project structure, in each of them you should set up different Application Descriptors with different app ids in tab "AIR Package".

Then you should create run configurations for each of them and run them.

Comment: So.. basically, different dummy modules pointing to the same code then?.

Comment: Oh, my mistake in definition. Not the module, just different "flash build configurations" in your current module. I'll fix it in answer.

Comment: But in fact - yes, different flash build configurations which are copy of each other with only one difference - different application descriptors with different ids

Comment: Will try it out as soon as I get home, would be great if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows? Can you use a "Run As" option (where you choose which account runs the installed app's **.exe** file?).

If you can do above, then just run one .exe instance as some **Current User** and then right-click and open the same .exe as **Administrator**. This allows two instances of same .exe to run...

Comment: Changing the build configurations did the trick. Check Selirion answer.